# TypeScript: Control the optional flag of a key based on usage

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types

I have an interface defined that has 6 properties. I want 1 of these properties to be mandatory in one workflow and optional for another workflow. I was trying to define a type along the lines of the following code snippet. This is similar to spreading all properties of an object and changing a few after the spread operation.

```
type Entity<T, Keys extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
  [S in Keys]: T[S];
};
```

However, this isn't doing the job. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are several solutions for this. One of these would be:

```
type Optional<T, OptionalKeys extends keyof T> =
    { [P in OptionalKeys]?: T[P] } & Omit<T, OptionalKeys>;
```

Here we define `OptionalKeys` and omitting them from required part.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUA0s8y6GA0hCAM5QQAewEKAJtQNYVIBmUOAfFAF4AUFFFQA3lADaABSgIUhRKkzkqAXQD8ALh6z1UAL5QAZLAC2CYLgJxlJNZV4BuKEKGhIUAGJIkgiSg0XRQAV3MAIwgAJwII3UpgaIUAcwIAY10IvwwINEVDZ3dPaAAhNGiAu2JMLF8kAgByNEaXd3TURKgIit1yyoFA+KhGxozdJNDoQvcAelmoAFFaSHTgGmjopGjdGS3IaNAR9Mb5aktKSlShDpQunuiAJj6KgMlh0aNnIA)